# Magento 2 How to Create Shipment Programmatically

Tags: shipping, sales-order, controllers

Here am trying to make shipment from a controller.
here is my controller

```
public function execute()
    {
      $orderId= 11;
      if ($orderId <= 0) {
         echo 'Order not found.';
         return;
      }
      try {
           // load order from database
           $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
           if ($order == null) {
              echo "Order not loaded from database.";
              // return;
            }
            $this->createShipment($order);
          } catch (\Exception $exception) {
                    echo 'Errorww: ' . $exception->getMessage();
    }
protected function createShipment($order)
    {
        if ($order->canShip()) {
            $shipment = $this->shipmentFactory->create($order);
            $this->shipmentRepository->save($shipment);
            $this->shipmentNotifier->notify($shipment);
        }
    }
```

Here am getting error as

```
Errorww: The shipment couldn't be saved.
```

Where am doing wrong. Can i get help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
// Load the order increment ID
$order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementID('000000001');

//load by order 
$order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load('1');

// Check if order can be shipped or has already shipped
if (! $order->canShip()) {
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('You can\'t create an shipment.')
                );
}

// Initialize the order shipment object
$convertOrder = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order');
$shipment = $convertOrder->toShipment($order);

// Loop through order items
foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {
    // Check if order item has qty to ship or is virtual
    if (! $orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
        continue;
    }

    $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();

    // Create shipment item with qty
    $shipmentItem = $convertOrder->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);

    // Add shipment item to shipment
    $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
}

// Register shipment
$shipment->register();

$shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

try {
    // Save created shipment and order
    $shipment->save();
    $shipment->getOrder()->save();

    // Send email
    $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier')
        ->notify($shipment);

    $shipment->save();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __($e->getMessage())
                );
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Rizwan Khan, this  is working

Comment: The `save()` method is deprecated. Is there an alternative way ? Thanks