# Creating shipments programmatically from order collection issue

Tags: magento2, shipment

This is my code:

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    if (!$order->canShip()) {
        continue;
    }
    // \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory
    $shipment = $this->shipmentFactory->create($order);
    try {
        //\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentRepository
        $this->shipmentRepository->save($shipment);
    } catch (Exception $error) {
        var_dump($error->getMessage());
    }
}
```

In my exception I am receiving this error message: `We cannot create an empty shipment.` from `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment::_beforeSave`

My goal is to create a shipment for each order from my order collection.
Any clue why my script is not working ? I found similar posts like: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/322459/6204 to create a shipment, but they are using deprecated methods. I would like to avoid that since I am running Magento `2.3.4`

Thanks

Comment: Check this link: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-shipment-programmatically.html

Comment: May this can help!

Comment: hi @AmitSaini as I mentioned in my post,  it uses deprecated method. See: this part : `$shipment->save();`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the existing API method, so when iterating the orders, pass each of them to a class that looks like this:

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Sales\Api\ShipOrderInterface;

class CreateShipments
{
    /**
     * @var ShipOrderInterface
     */
    protected $shipOrder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog
     */
    protected $monolog;

    /**
     * CreateShipments constructor
     *
     * @param ShipOrderInterface $shipOrder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog $monolog
     */
    public function __construct(
        ShipOrderInterface $shipOrder,        
        \Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog $monolog
    )
    {
        $this->shipOrder = $shipOrder;
        $this->monolog = $monolog;        
    }

    /**
     * Create shipments for a given order
     *
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
     */
    public function createShipmentForOrder($order)
    {
        try {
            $this->shipOrder->execute(
                $order->getId(),
                [],
                false,
                false,
                null,
                [],
                [],
                null
            );
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $this->monolog->critical($exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, you could only pass the order ID.

Cheers!

---

***LE:*** Oh and forgot to mention that maybe you need to add extra info, not sure, but check the definition of `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ShipOrder.php` and add the corresponding shipment details if needed. I just added a simplistic scenario above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
<?php
/**
* @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory
*/
protected $_shipmentTrackFactory;
 
/**
* @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory
*/
protected $_shipmentFactory;
 
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory
 */
protected $_transactionFactory;
 
/**
* @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
*/
protected $_orderRepository;
 
/**
* @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory $shipmentTrackFactory
* @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory $shipmentFactory
* @param \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory $transactionFactory
* @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
*/
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory $shipmentTrackFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory $shipmentFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory $transactionFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
    ) {
      $this->_shipmentTrackFactory = $shipmentTrackFactory;
      $this->_shipmentFactory = $shipmentFactory;
      $this->_transactionFactory = $transactionFactory;
      $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
}
 
/**
 * @param int $orderId
 * @param string $trackingNumber
 * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Shipment $shipment
 */
protected function createShipment($orderId, $trackingNumber)
{
    try {
        $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderId);
        if ($order){
            $data = array(array(
                'carrier_code' => $order->getShippingMethod(),
                'title' => $order->getShippingDescription(),
                'number' => $trackingNumber,
            ));
            $shipment = $this->prepareShipment($order, $data);
            if ($shipment) {
                $order->setIsInProcess(true);
                $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Automatically SHIPPED', false);
                $transactionSave =  $this->_transactionFactory->create()->addObject($shipment)->addObject($shipment->getOrder());
                $transactionSave->save();
            }
            return $shipment;
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            __($e->getMessage())
        );
    }
}
 
/**
* @param $order \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
* @param $track array
* @return $this
*/
protected function prepareShipment($order, $track)
{
   $shipment = $this->_shipmentFactory->create(
       $order,
       $this->prepareShipmentItems($order),
       $track
   );
   return $shipment->getTotalQty() ? $shipment->register() : false;
}
 
/**
* @param $order \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
* @return array
*/
protected function prepareShipmentItems($order)
{
   $items = [];
 
   foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
       $items[$item->getItemId()] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
   }
   return $items;
}
```

There are two main functions **prepareShipment** of `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory` class which prepare shipment and **addObject** of `\Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory` class which helps to create a shipment and associate the shipment with original order in Magento 2.

> Credit:
> https://www.scommerce-mage.com/blog/magento-2-how-to-create-shipment-programatically.html